# How to autologin using this vbscript

Tags: jquery, html, authentication, vbscript, automation

The below VBScript opens the webpage but it is not entering the username and password. While executing username part, It throws the message "The interface is unknown". Please help me to automate the login

Dim IE
    Dim Var

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1 
IE.navigate "www.webpage.com"
WScript.Sleep 10000
Set Var = IE.document.getElementByName("user").value = "myusername" 
Set Var = IE.document.getElementByID("password").value = "mypassword"
Set Var = IE.document.Forms(0)
Var.Submit
```

The Page Source is given in the link

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Var = IE.document.getElementByName("user").value = "myusername" 
Set Var = IE.document.getElementByID("password").value = "mypassword"
```

I feel above statements could be re written as

```
IE.document.getElementByName("user").value = "myusername" 
IE.document.getElementByID("password").value = "mypassword"
```

lastly you can click on login button as

```
IE.document.getElementByID("btnLogin").click
```

Comment: that click button worked. I cant able to enter user and password via script. Anyway I stored them in browser. Is there any source to explore more about Windows,Browser automation using VBScript ?

Comment: https://public.etherpad-mozilla.org/p/StackoverflowCode   Check this link I dont how to proceed with this. Clicking on this will launch an application.

Comment: Hi,

I did wrote small VBscript which opens google enters search criteria and clicks on google search.

   Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   IE.Visible = 1 
    IE.navigate "www.google.com"
   WScript.Sleep 10000
   IE.document.getElementById("lst-ib").value = "sandeep"
   msgbox(IE.document.getElementsByName("btnK").item(0).value)
   IE.document.getElementsByName("btnK").item(0).click

and this works fine. 

Also you can try sendkeys using object "wshshell" and send tabs and user names and passwords.

Comment: Also i found this article:

https://therevisionist.org/software-engineering/vbscript-tutorials/13-vbscript-internet-explorer-html-automation/